# gcs client library stopped working with dev_appserver

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Google cloud storage client library is returning 500 error when I attempt to upload via development server.

```
ServerError: Expect status [200] from Google Storage. But got status 500.
```

I haven't changed anything with the project and the code still works correctly in production.

I've attempted `gcloud components update` to get the latest dev_server and I've updated to the latest google cloud storage client library.

I've run `gcloud init` again to make sure credentials are loaded and I've made sure I'm using the correct bucket.

The project is running on windows 10.
Python version 2.7

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this has been a problem for a while.
It has to do with how blobstore filenames are generated.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35900575

The fix is to monkeypatch this file:
google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\blobstore\file_blob_storage.py

```
def _FileForBlob(self, blob_key):
  """Calculate full filename to store blob contents in.

  This method does not check to see if the file actually exists.

  Args:
    blob_key: Blob key of blob to calculate file for.

  Returns:
    Complete path for file used for storing blob.
  """
  blob_key = self._BlobKey(blob_key)
  # Remove bad characters.
  import re
  blob_fname = re.sub(r"[^\w\./\\]", "_", str(blob_key))
  # Make sure it's a relative directory.
  if blob_fname and blob_fname[0] in "/\\":
    blob_fname = blob_fname[1:]
  return os.path.join(self._DirectoryForBlob(blob_key), blob_fname)
```

Comment: Hi Rob, good work finding the solution! Can you accept your own answer? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!